# How to properly get message in JSON after form submision using Golang

Tags: go

How can I properly get message in JSON after form submission using Golang? I am trying Golang today for the first time.

Here is what am trying to achieve: in PHP for instance I can echo/print a JSON message after user submitted a form and can then access it from the front end.

Eg.

```
  if($everything == 'ok'){
 $messages = [
      'message' => 'User Registered successfully'
    ];
   echo json_encode($messages);
exit();
  }
```

How do I do this with Golang?

The code below works fine by inserting records to database. Upon a successful insert, it display a success message in the code below and everything is working fine.

```
res.Write([]byte("User Registered successfully!" +username))
```

How do I get JSON response of the successful message so that I can access it from my front end just like in PHP code above?

I have tried:

```
messageJson := `{"message": "User Registered successfully"}`
jsonresult_send := json.Marshal(messageJson)

return jsonresult_send
```

But it displays error **too many argument to return**.

Here is the entire code:

```
package main

import "database/sql"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

import "net/http"
import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

var db *sql.DB
var err error



type MessageInfo struct {
  Message string
}



func signupPage(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    if req.Method != "POST" {
        http.ServeFile(res, req, "signupjson.html")
        return
    }


    
        username := req.FormValue("username")
    password := req.FormValue("password")



    var user string
         err := db.QueryRow("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=?", username).Scan(&user)
     

    switch {
    case err == sql.ErrNoRows:
        _, err = db.Exec("INSERT INTO users(username, password) VALUES(?, ?)", username, password)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(res, "insert error, unable to create your account.", 500)
            return
        }

res.Write([]byte("User Registered successfully!" +username))

// get json response message

messageJson := `{"message": "User Registered successfully"}`
jsonresult_send := json.Marshal(messageJson)

return jsonresult_send

        return
    default:
        http.Redirect(res, req, "/", 301)
    }
}



func homePage(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(res, req, "index.html")
}

func main() {
    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", "root:@/golang44")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer db.Close()

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/signupjson", signupPage)
    http.HandleFunc("/", homePage)
        fmt.Println("Listening on 127.0.0.1:8088")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8088", nil)
}
```

Comment: Do I need something like coding below.                        //Set Content-Type header so that clients will know how to read response
 w.Header().Set("Content-Type","application/json")
 w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
 //Write json response back to response 
w.Write(jsonresult_send)

Comment: In my browser console, I need to be seing something like
an array or object of the json response. so that
I can finally use it with my front end code

[{"message": "User successfully Registered"}]

or

{"message": "User successfully Registered"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, what you need is this:

```
func GetPeople(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(people)
}
```

In your case, you could solve it in two ways:

1. With a struct

```
type Info struct {
    Message string `json:"message"`
}

func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ... Some processing here ...

    info := Info{Message: "User Registered successfully"}
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(info)
}
```

2. With a map

```
func MyHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    ... Some processing here ...

    info := map[string]string{"message": "User Registered successfully"}
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(info)
}
```

If anyone can test to look for some syntax error I appreciate it.